# approach for large payload transformation in Mule

Tags: json, mule, dataweave, mule-esb

I need to perform a json to json transformation of about 850 fields which also contains arrays. The mapping is one to one however is there any faster way to do it rather than mapping all the fields manually

Comment: Can you share your input and output files? If you want to arrive in a specific structure, you need it to map it manually. This is faster compare to other programming languages.

Comment: How do you exactly mean faster? Quicker to do in the UI of the Anypoint Studio or more performant?

Comment: Could you please share further details?